# R in Shiny: How can I adjust radio buttons to the grid width of column?

Tags: r, shiny

The question is straightforward. My code contains the following lines:

```
fluidRow(
   column(12, "some text"),
fluidRow(
   column(12, radioButtons("buttons", "please select a choice", choices = list("A" = 1, "B" = 2, "C" = 3), selected = FALSE, inline = TRUE)))
```

I would like the choices (radio buttons) to be evenly spread over the grid width. Any help is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You essentially need to use additional css parameters to do this.

Assuming parameters are your choices:

```
parameters <- c("A", "B", "C", "D")
```

To have a multi-column radio buttons: add additional class:

```
controls <-list(tags$div(align = 'left', 
                      class = 'multicol', 
                      radioButtons(inputId  = 'buttons', 
                                         label = "Select the parameters: ",
                                         choices  = parameters,
                                         selected = "A",
                                         inline   = FALSE), style = "font-size:90%"))
```

And apply css values to the added class:

```
tweaks <- list(tags$head(tags$style(HTML("
                                       .multicol { 
                                       height: 150px;
                                       -webkit-column-count: 5; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */ 
                                       -moz-column-count: 5;    /* Firefox */ 
                                       column-count: 5; 
                                       -moz-column-fill: auto;
                                       -column-fill: auto;
                                       } 
                                       ")) 
))
```

By resetting the column-count....you could fit the radio buttons across desired number of columns. You can use the object tweaks outside UI (before your UI starts or in global.R).  This will work for checkboxes too.