# Shiny - How to increase spacing between inline radio buttons?

Tags: r, shiny

I have a set of inline radio buttons:

```
radioButtons("buttons", 
             label = "Buttons",
             choices = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"),
             inline = T)
```

This makes them look like this:

[image: Buttons]

But I want there to be more spacing between the buttons, for example, to look like this:

[image: Buttons2]

It doesn't matter how this is done. It could be by setting the gap between the buttons to a certain number of pixels, or setting the spread of the buttons to a certain % of the page width.

Is there any way to do this?

[Related question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38630274/r-in-shiny-how-can-i-adjust-radio-buttons-to-the-grid-width-of-column), but not exactly the same (it's asking about fitting buttons to columns) and I can't get the code in the answer to work anyway.

Answer (score 3):

Using CSS, adjust the margin-right option:

```
.checkbox-inline, .radio-inline {
    margin-right: 100px;
}
```

I personally prefer to create a separate CSS file for my app's.
Within your app directory the CSS file should be located in a folder `'WWW'`.

Comment: Unless I'm using it wrong, this seems to move all of the radio buttons to the left, rather than space them out

Answer (score 1):

You can space the radio buttons by adding the following line before `radioButtons()` in the ui code:

```
tags$style(HTML(".radio-inline {margin-right: 42px;}")),
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm half a decade late but what you would have needed to specify is the padding, rather than the margin. Adding the following `tags$head()` somewhere in your UI does the trick.

```
tags$head(
  tags$style(
    HTML(".radio-inline, .checkbox-inline {padding-left: 40px;}")
  )
)
```